# Library of standard compiler warnings/errors

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am wondering whether you know of a way to demystify a given compiler warnings/error Xcode throws at you.

As a new developer to Objective-C, i would find it to be of value to know why some warnings happen, see examples of a  code that would cause an error and explain the solution.

Are you aware of any resources that offer more insight into this?

Comment: [O'Reilly Answers has a page](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2546-some-common-beginner-xcode-compiler-errors/) covering some of the most basic and common ones.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/introduction/introobjectivec.html seems to be the definitive documentation.  What don't you like about it? What's missing?  What problems does this create for  you?

Comment: @S.Lott: "The Objective-C Programming Language", to which you linked, is indeed the definitive document for the language, but it doesn't contain anything even _remotely_ resembling a list of compile-time error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"some warnings happen, see examples of a code that would cause an error and explain the solution."

It's best for you to provide code samples.

Why?

From http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/gcc-4.2.1/gcc/Standards.html#Standards

"There is no formal written standard for Objective-C or Objective-C++. The most authoritative manual is “Object-Oriented Programming and the Objective-C Language”, available at a number of web sites..."

This means that tt's best for you to provide a specific warning and the associated code.